# How can I hide inherited properties of an ASP.NET custom control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, custom-controls

Here is my first experience creating a custom control.  My real example is much larger, but this is boiled down for clarity.  Ultimately, I need to hide as many properties of the custom control as possible so that when I share my new control with the rest of my team, they need only worry about the few properties that are required.

I have a control called TimeNow which inherits `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal` and basically just prints the current time on the web page:

```
public class TimeNow : Literal

// Set to private so Text is hidden from the editor.
private string Text
{
    get;
    set;
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    // Get and write the time of now.
}
```

This *works*, but it seems clunky.  I no longer see Text available in intellisense when I drop the control on a web page, but I do receive a warning that my Text is hiding the inherited Text.  Is there a better way to hide the Text property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be more to that warning message, suggesting you use the `new` keyword if you *really* intend to hide the inherited member, do what it says:

```
public class TimeNow : Literal
{
    new private string Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, think about before doing that. This has several pitfalls. You can still access Literal.Text by cast ((Literal)myvar).Text. So you can still use your interface wrong, e.g. when loop through a list of Literals containing your TimeNow class. The Literal.Text variable is different from the one defined as private in TimeNow (now you have 2 of them)!!! Be careful using the new keyword here.

Comment: Hey, fascinating!  I read that part, but I just assumed it wasn't what I wanted to do.  Lesson learned.  Thanks!

Comment: @Beachwalker Thanks for the heads up!  I've discovered that if I set a property like Text declaratively, I'm still overriding it in my code; however, I really just want to reduce opportunities for confusion for my teammates.  Thanks!

Comment: @mrcoulson But this will definitely confuse your teammates because YOU ARE NOT OVERRIDING here and interfaces should be safe from being used in the wrong way. From my point of view this is not very clean coding and is a bad solution from my point of view. Have seen the usage of new in hacks only. A good Control should't need this.

Comment: Hence why I came here for better ideas :)  I knew it was bad, but I wasn't sure what the better answer was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
private string Text
{

}
```

Comment: This still leaves me hiding an inherited property.

Comment: I don't get what you mean! Don't you want to hide the property?

Comment: Maybe you should think about composition instead of inheritance. This way you can specify your own Interface and don't need to make something behave like something it wasn't meant to be used. Otherwise the Text property weren't defined and implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing something wrong if you derive from a `Literal` that behaves like an `ITextControl` (Literal has implemented this Interface) and then you try to remove the essential Text property? This is like deriving from cat but don't want to let them do "meow" and force them flying like a duck. You are searching for the Animal class instead, I think.

I don't know much about ASP.NET (only .Net for the Desktop). Maybe it is possible to use composition instead of inheritance (if you not really need the Literal -> "Cat") and you can inherit from `System.Web.UI.Control` (-> "Animal") instead.

```
public class TimeNow : System.Web.UI.Control
{
   // no need to do something here with the Text property, is not defined
}
```

or with composition

```
public class TimeNow : System.Web.UI.Control
{
     private readonly Literal literal;

     public TimeNow()
     {
         this.literal = new Literal();
         // ... and set the Text etc., no one else can access
     }

     // or something like this

     public TimeNow(ILiteralFactory literalFactory)
     {
         // the factory is just an example... don't know your context but this way your newly created literal can't be accessed
         this.literal = literalFactory.CreateNewLiteral();
         // do what you want with the text control, e.g. store internally
         // Clone() the Literal etc.
         // the
     }
}
```

**Update:** Had a very quick look into the MSDN and maybe a [Content Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content) is the thing you are looking for, instead of the Literal. (sorry if wrong, writing Desktop Apps)

Comment: Well, that all makes sense.  Really all I wanted to do for this example was have a control that would spit out some piece of text by itself on the page.  A literal seemed like the thing for just writing a few characters out to the page.  If this were the real implementation, this would totally make sense.

Comment: (Which is to say that when I return to work tomorrow and start writing the real control and not the one that writes a time on the page, I will start with this instead of where I left off.)